# WCF service that returns xml element

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

In my wcf service I need to return the status code as xmlelement.
If the POST method is sucess then I should pass

```
<xmlelement>success</xmlelement>
```

to the client.
if theres any error then
I should pass

```
<xmlelement>error</xmlelement>
```

to the client.
Any idea how to do this.
And is there any good site i can get good material abou this.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, ASMX web services only allowed you to return simple types. This often meant returning a string that contained XML. But, WCF did away with that. You can still return XML as a string, if you want. But, there's no need to. You can return any .NET object you want from your WCF service.

For something as simple as "it worked vs. it failed with this error" I often just return a string. If the string is empty, that indicates success. Otherwise, the string contains the error message.

You could also use a simple class or struct to do something like this:

```
public struct Result
{
    bool Success,
    string ErrorMessage
}
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: I believe the OP is talking about REST WCF (based on his comment about POST) - not sure your answer would apply to REST (never done REST services myself), but it's accurate for SOAP WCF (though it would normally be implemented via a DataContract).

Comment: It seems my <xmlelement> tag was not displayed in the original question. I have updated the question.

Comment: Yes I am using REST Wcf Service. Any ideas, how it can be done.

Comment: @Tim - Right on. I neglected to include the [DataContract] gibberish.

Comment: @Henry - Sorry, no experience doing REST with WCF

Comment: @Henry - Doesn't a RESTful service return HTTP 200 for success? And, a different HTTP return code for failure?